# Run chromium instead of google chrome with cordova browser platform

Tags: cordova, chromium

I am on Arch Linux and I use Chromium as my main browser. I started using Cordova to develop cross-platform apps and my problem is :

When I run `cordova run browser`, everything seems normal except that there is an error because Cordova would like to launch Google Chrome but I would like Cordova launches Chromium instead.

`Error executing "google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_user_data_dir_for_cordova http://localhost:8000/index.html": /bin/sh: google-chrome : command not found`

If anyone knows how to replace google-chrome with chromium for this command it would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the `--target` option in the command line.

```
cordova run browser --target=chromium
```

Comment: Thank you dude ! :)